# Duplicate numbers printed by child process

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to create a child process for each of the inner loop, but I keep getting duplicated results. I guess this is because the child processes created after each iteration try to access the same file for the same piece of data. How do I stop them from obtaining duplicated numbers? *data.txt* contains only 1 integer which is 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    FILE *fptr;
    int N, i, j;
    //each of the process obtaining 200 integers from file a.txt
    pid_t pid;
    for(i=0;i<200;i++) {
    //loop for performing the given 8 steps by each process
        for(j=1;j<4;j++){
            pid= fork();
            fptr = fopen("data.txt","r");//step 1
            fscanf(fptr,"%d",&N);//step 2
            fclose(fptr);//step 3
            printf("N=%d ProcessId=P%d\n", N, j);//step 4
            N=N+1;//step 5
            fptr = fopen("data.txt","w");//step 6
            fprintf(fptr,"%d",N);//step 7
            fclose(fptr);//step 8
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fopen("data.txt","w")` will truncate the file.  You are doing that many, many times.  (How many processes are running if you fork 200 times in a loop?  Many more than 200.)

Comment: `pid= fork();` Fork duplicates the process and returns twice - once in the parent where its result is the pid of the child, and once in the child with the return value of 0.  (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) .  You should be checking the value of `pid` to decide whether to continue the loop (parent) or run the child code.  Remember to also wait for the child processes if you want to make sure they end before parent.

Comment: You should probably first do the exercise of understanding how many processes are executed when you do `for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) { fork(); }`

Comment: I tried to add a condition to check whether pid = 0 inside of the inner loop, if it is then exit(0). However, I expect the code to fork 600 times, 200 times for each interation of the inner loop. However, it only forked 13 times. Could you please explain, and how do I implement it so that I will have a total of 600 child processes

Comment: pid= fork();
           if (pid == 0) {
   printf("Child Process\n");
  exit(0);
    }
Here is my condition

Comment: You could be running into a process limit. `fork()` returns a negative result if it gets an error, check for that and print the error message with `perror()`.

Comment: Unless your goal is to try to start more than a googol processes, that's the wrong way to use `fork()`.

Comment: Without an `exit`, your code is going to attempt to create 2^800 processes.  That's significantly more than the estimated number of atoms in the universe.